Typescript discriminated unions using subfield/metadata type
Right now I have a response type coming from an ES database that I cannot really alter the shape of.  It has a different value type depending on the response type. I tried using discriminated unions to help with if block type narrowing like below:
inferface NumberResponse {
    metadata: {
        response_type: 'number';
    };
    value: number;
}

inferface BooleanResponse {
    metadata: {
        response_type: 'boolean';
    };
    value: boolean;
}

type Response = NumberResponse | BooleanResponse;

Yet, unfortunately, it does not appear to do what I would like:
let response: Response;

if(response.metadata.response_type === 'boolean') {
    // this results in value being defined as number | boolean
    // I was hoping/expecting it to be narrowed to boolean
    let value = response.value; 
}

I'm assuming this kind of type narrowing is not possible. Any suggestions, tips, or information is much appreciated, as I've had a hard time googling this. Thanks!

No, TS doesn't support nested discriminated unions; see the feature request at ms/TS#18758 and possible approaches in the linked q/a above. You could build your own property guarding function as shown in this approach.
